# Convert JSON Unicode escape sequences of the form '\uA90F' to XML character references using VB Script RegExp object

Tags: json, regex, xml, unicode, vbscript

I want to convert JSON Unicode escape sequences of the form `\uA90F` to XML character references of the form `&#xA90F&#59;`.

The `Replace` in the script below is working, but I cannot figure out how to substitute back into the original string, so that this:

`Zo\u00EB  C\u00E9cile Fran\u00E7oise`

Becomes:

`Zo&amp;#x00EB; C&amp;#x00E9;cile Fran&amp;#x00E7;oise`

```
Dim RegX, InputText, Pattern, ReplacedText

            'Zoe        Francoise       Cecile
InputText = "Zo\u00E2   Fran\u00E7oise  C\u00E9cile"

SearchPattern = "\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}"

set RegX = New RegExp
RegX.Pattern = SearchPattern
RegX.Global = True

Set Matches = RegX.Execute(InputText)
For Each Match In Matches
    s = Replace(Match, "\u", "&#x") & ";" '<-- ** This works fine **
    MsgBox(s)
Next
```

Comment: Can't help because I don't know VBScript, but please note that this approach won't work for "astral" characters such as Emoji -- XML uses a single escape sequence containing the unicode code point value, for example `&#x1F600;` whereas JSON encodes the two parts of the UTF-16 surrogate pair `\uD83D\uDE00`

Answer (score 1):

You need to match hex chars with `[A-Fa-f0-9]`, not `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Also, you need to use a capturing group around the pattern you need to keep in the result, and a backreference in the `RegExp.Replace` method (you needn't first collect the matches).

So, you can use

```vb
Dim RegX, InputText, ReplacedText

InputText = "Zo\u00E2   Fran\u00E7oise  C\u00E9cile"

Set RegX = New RegExp
RegX.Pattern = "\\u([a-fA-F0-9]{4})"
RegX.Global = True

ReplacedText = RegX.Replace(InputText, "&#x$1;")
  
MsgBox(ReplacedText)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7h2PjM/1).

Comment: As MichaelKay mentioned in another comment, this approach won't work correctly for encoded Unicode characters > `U+FFFF`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Let's keep to the original problem: *"The Replace in the script below **is working**, but I cannot figure out **how to substitute back into the original string**"*

Answer (score -1):

*Note: as @MichaelKay mentioned in comments, what you are attempting to do will only work for Unicode characters <= `U+FFFF`.  For higher-valued codepoints, the code will get a bit more more complicated.*

Each `Match` has three properties:

- `Value` - the actual text in the search string that was matched.
- `FirstIndex` - the 0-based index of the first character of the match in the search string.
- `Length` - the length of the matched string.

So, you know exactly where each `Match` was found in the `InputText` string.  You can use that information to create a new string with the replaced substrings in it, eg:

```vb
Dim RegX, InputText, SearchPattern, ReplacedText, S, StartIdx, FoundIdx

            'Zoe        Francoise       Cecile
InputText = "Zo\u00E2   Fran\u00E7oise  C\u00E9cile"

SearchPattern = "\\u([a-fA-F0-9]{4})"

set RegX = New RegExp
RegX.Pattern = SearchPattern
RegX.Global = True

Set Matches = RegX.Execute(InputText)

StartIdx = 1
ReplacedText = ""

For Each Match In Matches
    S = Replace(Match.Value, "\u", "&#x") & ";"
    MsgBox(S)
    FoundIdx = Match.FirstIndex + 1
    If FoundIdx > StartIdx Then
        ReplacedText = ReplacedText + Mid(InputText, StartIdx, FoundIdx - StartIdx)
    End If
    ReplacedText = ReplacedText + S
    StartIdx = FoundIdx + Match.Length
Next

If StartIdx <= Len(InputText) Then
    ReplacedText = ReplacedText + Mid(InputText, StartIdx)
End If
```

Alternatively, you could just use the `RegExp.Replace()` method, like 
[@WiktorStribiżew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70297284/65863) demonstrates.

Comment: Wiktor's example was the one I used and it worked perfectly.

 -- Comment's on higher-valued codepoints noted.

Thanks all for your input.